# COM reference counting - thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, reference

If I have a COM object, is it required for the AddRef() and Release() methods to be thread-safe- i.e., that I have to use atomic operations for my ref count?

Comment: Same rule applies as to other methods. STA COM object does not need to care about thread safety, MTA COM object - has to (InterlockedXxx is the easiest approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the free threaded aparement model, use InterlockedIncrement() and InterlockedDecrement() to handle the ref count.

Comment: Using InterlockedIncrement() etc. is the general idiom and it's thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is no.  It is not **required**.  If you want your COM object to be thread safe then those should be thread safe. Otherwise they do not have to be.

E.g. if you look here: [The Rules of the Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx) it is not mentioned as a requirement.
Also [The COM Programmer's Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809982.aspx) (Building a COM Component) you can see a sample object without thread safe reference counting.

Microsoft code snippet:

```
ULONG COutside::AddRef (void)
{
    return ++ m_cRef;
}
```

In practice most implementations would do this because otherwise the COM objects would not be thread safe. If you know the object will only be used in one thread I believe it is an allowed optimization.  Not all COM objects are thread safe, I've worked with a few that weren't.

To deal with the fact that COM objects may or may not be thread safe COM offers different "apartments" in which COM objects are created.  In a single threaded apartment only a single thread can access objects within that apartment whereas in multi threaded apartment objects can be shared between multiple threads.  Quoting from [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx):

> "Although multi-threaded apartments,
>   sometimes called free-threaded
>   apartments, are a much simpler model,
>   they are more difficult to develop for
>   because the developer must implement
>   the thread synchronization for the
>   objects, a decidedly nontrivial task."

Comment: Your answer, though not entirely useless, is dangerously incomplete. You should at least mention the possibility of free threaded access (which the linked page, for reasons beyond my comprehension, does not mention either)

Comment: It is nevertheless correct.  It is up to the programmer not to use thread unsafe objects in the wrong compartment.  Is it dangerous?  Yes.  But I didn't make it that way.  I'll add notes about this to my answer.

Comment: To be honest: I think most COM objects aren't freethreading (in fact back in the days, I got the distinct impression that MS Gurus were making it out to be the biggest technological stunt of the century to make a freethreaded COM object); It was/is the culture of COM to hide the complexity of threading and automatically marshal across apartment boundaries. However, since the question was open-ended **and** specifically mentioned threadsafety, you should at least mention the free-threaded scenario :) Which now you do, hat tip

Comment: @sehe: That was my experience as well.  I answered the question literaly, whether or not it is **required**  in COM that those are thread safe.  Perhaps I needed to add more background - still getting used to this SO thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yup. That is required. COM is a simple binary standard and if you use Free Threaded Apartments, you'll get truly free threaded accesses

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the threading model you use and the kind of object. Please see the description of [`_ATL_*_THREADED` macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9t07f8b4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Those macros affect thread-safety of `AddRef()/Release()` of "usual" classes and of factories.

If you use a "too loose" macro you violate thread-safety requirements and your program might malfunction. If you choose a "too tight" macro you might lose some performance, but you as usual don't know if you care before you profile.

Here's how you choose the right macro (and this explains whether `AddRef()/Release()` have to be thread-safe).

If all the classes of a single server have no threading model specified (Main STA) then there's no chance of concurrent access to either objects or factories and they all can have non-threadsafe `AddRef()/Release()` and you get this by specifying `_ATL_SINGLE_THREADED` macro.

Otherwise if at least one class has "Apartment" model specified you need thread-safe `AddRef()/Release()` for the factory of that object but still can have a non-threadsafe `AddRef()/Release()` in the object itself and you get this by specifying `_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED` macro. This macro will make all factories have thread-safe `AddRef()/Release()` and all object - non-threadsafe `AddRef()/Release()`.

Finally if at least one class has "Both" or "Free" threading model specified you need `AddRef()/Release()` to be thread-safe in both that class and in the factory and you have to either specify `_ATL_FREE_THREADED` or just not specify any of the above - this "most tight" macro effect will be on by default. So the default configuration for COM objects created using ATL is to have thread-safe `AddRef()/Release()` for all objects - both served objects and factories.

That said you don't always need `AddRef()/Release()` to be thread-safe, but you usually should unless you know for sure that you can get without it and that getting without it lets you gain performance.